# Generate and embed string in quotation marks

Tags: excel, string, quotation-marks

I have a column of numbers demarking ages (5-100) within a cohort (B4:B99). I want to use the values within this column as a unique string within another function =FUNCTION("string",value). The function requires the string to be within quotation marks. Can I source the string name from the age column for each row and somehow place that new string within quotation marks?

For instance for Row Four I have the value 5 in the age column. I want to be able to place that into the new formula in such a was as it is recognisable as a string. =FUNCTION("5", value).

I know I can use TEXT to generate the string but this doesn't place the string within quotation marks.

Comment: Do you need to enclose `value` with double quotes? Just use `"""" & value & """"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Like this =TEXT("""A10""", 0) ? That gives me the cell reference as the string, not the value within it. If I add the ampersand symbols as indicated then they just appear within the string. In my sheet, cell A10 contains the value 11 and I want that to appear in my new column as I can then use it as a string name for a further function.

Comment: Close but not quite. You'd need to use `CONCATENATE` or to include the `&`'s (which also concatenate). You can also use `CHAR(34)` in place of `""""`. More characters, but it's a little easier to read